# Why getElementById does not work on elements other than document?

Tags: javascript

Why `document.body.getElementById(idOfElem)` and `document.body.getElementsByName(nameOfElem)` not working?

and

Why `document.body.getElementByTagName(tagOfElem)` and `document.body.getElementByClassName(classOfElem)` working?

When using the first, the browser throw this error:

> TypeError: document.body.getElementById is not a function[Learn More]

Comment: Drop the `body` part. It's just `document.getElementById`

Comment: Use `document.getElementById()` and if `idOFelem` is not a variable use `"idOFelem"`

Comment: @Teemu the OP isn't asking what the methods do. Instead the OP is confused about why `getElementById` is not available on the `body` object,  but the others are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementById` is a method of `document`, not of `document.body`. The same goes for `getElementsByName`.

On the other hand, `getElementByTagName` and `getElementByClassName` can be called on any element including `body`.

Comment: document.body.getElementsByName(idOFelem) not work??


why document.body.getElementByTagName(idOFelem) work?? why document.body.getElementByClassName(idOFelem) work??

Comment: @hamidreza `.getElementById` is only a method of `document`, the other methods you've listed are also methods of `document.body`. Such is the DOM.

Answer (score 6):

Since IDs are unique you have to use `document.getElementById` as it is the only DOM element that have that function.

Elements other than `document` have these functions: `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName`, `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` but not the `getElementById`.

**Why not define it on elements other than document?**

An element with an ID is unique no matter what its parent is. Therefore, it's uncessary to know the parent of an element before getting that element using its ID. So, there's no need to put the function `getElementById` on all elements, putting it only on `document` will suffice.

**Why are the other functions defined?**

Because you sometimes need to get the `<div>`s or `<p>`s or elements with some class `.cls` only if they're inside a known element. Then if you use `document` as the root, the result will be all the elements in the document not just the ones inside your desired element.

**Conclusion:**

`document.getElementById` will always return at most one element, hence why redefining it on every DOM element (it will be useless). But other functions like `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementByClassName`, ... could return as many as there could be. So we put them on all elements so that we can narrow the search by specifying a root to start the search from.

Comment: document.body.getElementsByName(idOFelem) not work??

and

why document.body.getElementByTagName(idOFelem) work?? why document.body.getElementByClassName(idOFelem) work??

Comment: Of course! Why would an element have an id select method?

Comment: @evolutionxbox exactly!

Answer (score 0):

`document.body.getElementById()` does not exist. 
Use `document.getElementById()` gets the element with the matching ID from the document.

`document.getElementsByTagName()` -  gets all the elements which match the tag name from the document.